# Downloadable recordings of individual Mongolian words

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, mongolian, speaking

I'm working on an Anki deck for Mongolian. The book "Fluent Forever" suggests including recordings of words if possible. The book suggests using forvo.com for recordings, and it's pretty good, except that it only sometimes has the words I'm after.

bolor-toli.com has pronunciations, but they're not downloadable, and I'm not sure about the suitability of http://www.studymongolian.net/dictionary/ , as it's dedicated to the Mongolian of Inner Mongolia (China), and I'm not sure whether they're of people or computer-generated.

What other resources are there for downloadable recordings of individual Mongolian words?

Comment: Have you tried [rhinospike.com](https://rhinospike.com/)? It supports Mongolian, but I don't know how many native speakers use it who would respond to requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The audio from the two resources you mentioned (bolor-toli.com and studymongolian.net) can be downloaded, using these two bookmarklets:

[bolor-toli.com](http://bolor-toli.com/dictionary/word?search=incredible&selected_lang=4-1&see_usages=true&see_variants=true):

```
javascript:!function(){function e(e,t,n,a,r,c){var o="/dictionary/sounds",i={word:a,trans_id:r,lang_id:c,notfound_message:t},l="script",s="POST",u=$.ajax({type:s,url:o,data:i,async:!1,dataType:l,beforeSend:function(e){e.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token",$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"))}}).responseText;try{var d=document.createElement("html");d.innerHTML=u;var p=document.createElement("a");p.href=d.querySelector("audio source").src,p.target="_blank",p.innerHTML='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i>',e.parentNode.appendChild(p)}catch(h){}}[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td a[href="javascript:void(0)"][onclick~="\'2\')"][onclick*="showSounds"]'),function(t){var n=t.getAttribute("onclick");n=n.replace("showSounds(this, ","").replace(")","");var a=n.split("',").map(function(e){return e.trim().substr(1)});a.unshift(t),a[a.length-1]="2",e.apply(null,a)})}();
```

[image: Bookmarklet demo]

Use on the search page. Generates a download link next to the audio play button. Note that it takes a while to load, because it has to make a network request to get the link for each audio file. Also, not every word has audio.

[studymongolian.net](http://www.studymongolian.net/dictionary/)

```
javascript:!function(){[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myButton_play"),function(e){var t=e.getAttribute("onclick").split(",")[2].replace(/'/g,""),n=document.createElement("a");n.target="_blank",n.href=t,n.innerHTML="Download",e.parentNode.appendChild(n)})}();
```

[image: Bookmarklet demo]

Generates a "Download" link next to the play button on the page you mentioned.

Of course, I cannot guarantee these two will work, that they will function properly, etc, especially when/if these pages ever change.

Comment: I was curious as to how these bookmarklets are applied and did a little search. There is probably a simpler way, but this is what I came up with (for Firefox, but should be similar for other browsers): Show the Bookmarks Toolbar by right-clicking on an empty section of the Tab Strip (at the very top of the browser window) and checking 'Bookmarks Toolbar' in the pop-up menu. Copy the bookmarklet provided by Hatchet (easiest way: double click on the first word -i.e.'javascript'- and press shift+end, then ctrl+c). Right-klick on the Bookmarks Toolbar and select 'Paste' in the pop-up menu...

Comment: Then browse to the corresponding site (you can simply use the link provided by Hatchet), and when the page has loaded press the corresponding bookmarklet in the Bookmarks Toolbar. Wait until the script has finished running and the download-buttons for all extant audio have appeared. Ready to go...   Edits: 1) If you’re using Chrome or Internet Explorer press Ctrl+Shift+B to show your Bookmarks Toolbar. 2) Instead of copying and pasting the bookmarklet you can simply drag and drop it onto the Bookmarks Toolbar.